# Initialize class properties outside Init function

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry if this is a basic problem, but I could not find a resolution anywhere. I would like to initialize class properties in a function outside of Init, and only call it from inside the constructor. I am doing this to avoid code duplication, as the current version looks like this:

```
public class WifiNameDisplay: UIView {
    var wifiImageView: UIImageView
    var networkName: UILabel
    public var networkSSID: String {
        didSet {
            networkName.text = networkSSID
            adjustSizeToContent()
        }
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        networkSSID = "NETWORK"
        wifiImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "wifi_icon.png")!)
        networkName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: wifiImageView.frame.size.height)))

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }


    convenience public init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        networkSSID = "NETWORK"
        wifiImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "wifi_icon.png")!)
        networkName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: wifiImageView.frame.size.height)))

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
}
```

And i would like to change it to something like this:

```
public class WifiNameDisplay: UIView {
    var wifiImageView: UIImageView
    var networkName: UILabel
    public var networkSSID: String {
        didSet {
            networkName.text = networkSSID
            adjustSizeToContent()
        }
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        initDefaultValues()
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }


    convenience public init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        initDefaultValues()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func initDefaultValues() {
        networkSSID = "NETWORK"
        wifiImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "wifi_icon.png")!)
        networkName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: wifiImageView.frame.size.height)))
    }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler does not allow that, calling "Use of 'self' in method call 'initDefaultValues' before super.init initializes self". Is what I want even possible, or am I forced to use duplicate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your properties as implicitly unwrapped optionals then you can initialise them after you call the superclass init functions -

```
public class WifiNameDisplay: UIView {
    var wifiImageView: UIImageView!
    var networkName: UILabel!
    public var networkSSID: String! {
        didSet {
            networkName.text = networkSSID
          //  adjustSizeToContent()
        }
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        initDefaultValues()
    }


    convenience public init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        initDefaultValues()
    }

    func initDefaultValues() {
        networkSSID = "NETWORK"
        wifiImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "wifi_icon.png")!)
        networkName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: wifiImageView.frame.size.height)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept this answer as you were a minute faster :) Both you and @libec get a vote up though.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways as far as I know. Initialize the values when you define them:

```
public class WifiNameDisplay: UIView {
    var wifiImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "wifi_icon.png")!)
    var networkName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: wifiImageView.frame.size.height)))
    public var networkSSID = "Network"
}
```

But this will not work for you, because `networkName` doesn't know about `wifiImageView` in this scope, so it won't be able to find the correct frame for it. I find this useful for simpler use cases like setting up offset, string constants and so on, but wouldn't recommend using this for UI elements.

Other way is to make variables (implicitly unwrapped) optional and call `initDefaultValues` after `super.init`:

```
public class WifiNameDisplay: UIView {
    var wifiImageView: UIImageView!
    var networkName: UILabel!
    public var networkSSID: String! {
        didSet {
            networkName.text = networkSSID
        }
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initDefaultValues()
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        initDefaultValues()
    }

    func initDefaultValues() {
        networkSSID = "NETWORK"
        wifiImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "wifi_icon.png")!)
        networkName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: wifiImageView.frame.size.height)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the property you want to initialize outside of init function to lazy property:

```
lazy var  networkName:UILabel = { return UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400,     
                                  height: self. wifiImageView.frame.size.height)))}()
```